# AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, python-2.7, geopandas

So I have tried this:

```
import GeoDataFrame
```

But it shows the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-3125c1efb589> in <module>
----> 1 import GeoDataFrame

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'GeoDataFrame'
```

when I install on cmd using the command:

```
pip install GeoDataFrame

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement GeoDataFrame (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for GeoDataFrame
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to install it via `pip install geopandas`. Go go through their [documentation](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) for using geodataframe.

Answer (score 1):

'GeoDataFrame' is a class inside the module `geopandas`. Installing `geopandas` will solve the problem. Use the following terminal command to install:

```
pip install geopandas`
```

Then use `import geopandas` for using its functionality. [Here's](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/CSC18/course-info/course-info.html) the great tutorial for working with GIS.